# Detecting "Error 106 net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED)"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there anyway to detect in a background extension when Chrome shows the page "Error 106 (net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED): The Internet connection has been lost." ?  I have tried registering a listener with both `chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener` and `chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred.addListener` but neither listener is called when a "Error 106" occurs.  My listeners are being called correctly for other errors such as "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED".

I'm targeting Chrome 22.0.1229.94 in a Window 7 environment.  The larger goal is to provide custom messaging (in a separate tab) when Internet connectivity is lost.

Comment: Have you tried the `navigator.onLine` property and/or the `window.ononline`/`window.onoffline` events instead?

Comment: Rob W, those worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: I really wouldn't trust the navigator.onLine as I've found a lot of cases where it doesn't actually represent a true internet connectivity but more a connection to your local network/router

Comment: Were you ever able to find a way to distinguish between ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED and net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED?

Answer (score 3):

I personally ended up testing for response == "" and status == 0.

```
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("post", VALIDATE_URL, true);
        req.onreadystatechange = function receiveResponse() {

            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    console.log("We go a response : " + this.response);
                } else if (!isValid(this.response) && this.status == 0) {
                    console.log("The computer appears to be offline.");
                }
            }
        };
        req.send(payload);
        req = null;
```

Comment: This happens for both net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED so it's not super helpful, sadly